# Google storage bucket and Google colab

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-colaboratory

i'm using the colab and google drive. 
what is the main difference between using google drive and google storage bucket.

and my team open the storage bucket on google bucket

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
project_id = 'nifty-depth-246308'
!gcloud config set project {project_id}
!gsutil ls

bucket_name = 'medium_demo_bucket_190710'
!gsutil -m cp -r /content/drive/My\ Drive/Data/* gs://{bucket_name}/
```

and using this way to copy the google bucket data to google drive.
this seems like just copy to the google drive.
is there direct access and use the google colab and google storage buckete?

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive is a cloud storage option with bigger integration with other Google Apps platform (Sheets, Docs, Presentation etc.) but is not the same as Google Cloud Storage because it does not provide for any business-ready features like:

- No tier-based data storage
- It is not a business solution (Google preserves Google Cloud Storage but not Google Drive as an enterprise platform, so you will not get a solid business application with Google Drive data storage)
- It doesn't support advanced data management features (there are no buckets that preserve all your project data, no management of object metadata, no setting of object and bucket ACLs)
- Weak load-bearing capacity

Basically, Google Drive is a good solution for personal use, and Google Cloud Storage is better suited for small and medium business that want to focus on the more extensive, functional part of their business.

And regarding your second question, you cannot use Cloud Storage to upload files to services in G Suite, such as Google Drive.

I found this [blog](http://ericscuccimarra.com/blog/colab-and-cloud-storage) post that explains how to save files from Google Colab to Google Cloud Storage.